# Blurry text on GLCanvas

Tags: java, opengl, canvas, jogl, text-rendering

I have a simple custom Canvas

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.glu.GLU;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer;

import java.awt.*;

public class MyCanvas extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener {

private GLU glu;

public MyCanvas() {
    this.addGLEventListener(this);
}

TextRenderer renderer;
@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    renderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 16));

    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    glu = new GLU();
    gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    if (height == 0) height = 1;
    float aspect = (float)width / height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -50f);
    gl.glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glEnd();

    String text = "Text";
    renderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.begin3DRendering();
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslated(0, 0, 0);
    renderer.draw(text, 0, 0);
    renderer.flush();
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    renderer.end3DRendering();
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }
}
```

And I have a simple JFrame for displaying this canvas.

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class App extends JFrame {

private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;
private static final int FPS = 60;

public App() {
    GLCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

    final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, FPS, true);

    this.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (animator.isStarted()) animator.stop();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
    this.setTitle("JOGL (GLCanvas)");
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    animator.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(App::new);
}
}
```

When I run programm I see very blurry text.
[image]

And when I reduce text size, then text became is more and more blurry. What should I do to get a clear text?

Comment: Does it change anything if you create the font with a larger size?

Comment: @BDL Of cousre, my text became larger. But I no needed in very big text

Comment: I should have written more clearly what I meant: It seems that the texture size the font-renderer uses is too small for the size the text is rendered at. The blurry part comes from the bi-linear interpolation on this texture.

Comment: By the way, you should replace "new GLU()" by "GLU.createGLU(GL)", you're currently creating a not very capable generic GLU instance which can throw unsupported operation exceptions in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is blurry, because the font size doesn't match the rendered size on screen and bi-linear interpolation is used to magnify the font/font-texture.

The problem might happen because you are mixing 2D and 3D text rendering functions. You should either use `begin3DRendering`, `draw3D` and `end3DRendering`, where you can control the actual size of the text with the scaling parameter, or you use `beginRendering`, `draw` and `endRendering` where a orthographic projection is used to map pixels from the font to the screen.

Comment: Thanks, friend! You really save my time!